# Use of fnmatch.filter to filter list of strings in python is right?

Tags: python, string

I have list of URLs in variable `categories` and I want to filter the list to obtain URLs in which `http` is present.

```
//categories contains list of urls
filtered = set(fnmatch.filter(categories,'http*'))
```

Comment: Thank you formatting the code captainwardrobe. And people who down voted the question I respect your views but this is my first time on stack overflow and already they've blocked me from asking questions. I am new to python and the question I asked was after reading the suggestions and researching for long time. Take it easy folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work but `set(c for c in categories if c.startswith('http'))` is more direct as it doesn't build a filtered list before turning that into a set.

Comment: Thank you Dan! but which is the most efficient way? As we're using _for_ loop here and I have 10000 strings to parse

Comment: This takes 2.3 msec. The set filter takes 5.56 msec. For a list of 10000 `'http'`s

Comment: Okay. Thanks again :)